# How to migrate large blob table from mysql to postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I'm now in process of migrating my MySQL database to PostgreSQL. Almost everything went fine (well, after lots of googling for correct mysqldump params etc.) except one table I have - actually the most important table in my app.

Table structure is very simple:

```
mysql> show create table samples;
.. skipped ...
CREATE TABLE `samples` (
      `File_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `File` longblob,
      PRIMARY KEY (`File_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary
```

but it is **very** large (> 20 Gb).

I've tried to use --hex-blob parameter of mysqldump - but data in this format is not accepted by PostgreSQL when I tried to use resulting dumpfile as a command file. Another option I've tried is using --tab option to just get a dump and then insert it to PostgreSQL with COPY command - but --hex-blob is not working with --tab and PostgreSQL still does not accept the dumpfile saying there are invalid characters in it.

I'd be very glad to get any advice on this matter - although I'm starting to think that writing a custom migration tool is not a bad idea after all...

Comment: Last I checked, [PostgreSQL's dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) could only connect to other PostgreSQL instances.  I don't think [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy) is any better.  You might need to use your favorite language (IE: Java, etc) to read from MySQL in order to insert into PostgreSQL...

Comment: @OMG: As I've noticed in question, I'm almost ready to go this way - just have a slight hope that someone knows something on this matter.

Comment: What data type on pgsql's end are you trying to insert it into?  I'd do bytea myself.

Comment: @Scott: Yes, of course it's bytea.

Comment: posgresql 9 supports hex syntax for bytea directly, see here : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-binary.html#AEN5037 (you'll need a bit of sed though)

Comment: Please don't crosspost in future, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that simplest way is to use that `--hex-blob` switch on [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) and restore by psql, with [`decode(string text, type text)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER). However it's not that simple, because you need to change a little produced dump (sed, awk), adding that decode function. For example:

```bsh
mysqldump -u root -p --skip-quote-names --hex-blob --skip-triggers \
    --compact --no-create-info mysql samples > prepg.dump

sed "s/0x\([0-9,A-F]*\))/decode('\1','hex'))/g" prepg.dump > pg.dump
```

psql session:

```
CREATE TABLE samples
(
    file_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    file bytea
);

\i 'path/to/pg.dump'
```

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, Grzegorz, I'll give this a try and report the results.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Test 10 files imported correctly, all the checksums are matching originals. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have other fields you won't want it to match commas or the trailing parenthesis. This should work: `sed "s/0x\([0-9A-F]*\)/decode('\1','hex')/g" prepg.dump > pg.dump`

Comment: I think it's helpful to understand that the sed expression is stripping off the `0x` and then wrapping the rest in the decode function.  So, if your input is `0xDD76A2A5E2`, your output will be `decode('DD76A2A5E2','hex')`