# mysql to postgresql, migrate files directly ( longblob > pg_largeobject )

Tags: mysql, postgresql, python, blob

I'm working on a python(2.6.6.) script and I'm evaluating what approach to take to migrate files from mysql-server to PostgreSQL . I've read the following posts:

- [How to insert (file) data into a PostgreSQL bytea column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column)
- [How to migrate large blob table from mysql to postgresql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/how-to-migrate-large-blob-table-from-mysql-to-postgresql)

But in both cases [large object interfaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/lo-funcs.html) are used, and files are dumped from mysql **into OS file system**, which is not what I want.

**I'm looking for a way to directly import the mysql longblobs into postgresql**, without have to previously write them into OS filesystem. I believe that this approach will increase the overall migration performance since less 'steps' are required.

And also because my code structure looks to be ready to hold such kind of modification, because I already have to iterate each row of the tables that contain files data in order to convert some fields and make other kind of transformations.

### example:

this is `mysql` source table :

```
describe source_table;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RESOURCE_ID | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| PAGE        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| VERSION     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| CONTENT     | longblob            | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CURRENT     | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

this is `postgresql` destination table :

```
\d+ destination_table;
                     Table "public.destination_table"
   Column    |   Type   |     Modifiers      | Storage  | Description 
-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+-------------
 resource_id | bigint   | not null default 0 | plain    | 
 version     | smallint | not null default 0 | plain    | 
 page        | smallint | not null default 0 | plain    | 
 file_oid    | oid      |                    | plain    |
```

This is my pseudo-code ( pseudo because the largeobject import part does not work and it's actually imaginative ) :

```
def migrate_files(function_args):

  for key, values in function_args.items():
    cur_msql = cnx_msql.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cur_psql = cnx_psql.cursor()

  ### SELECT DATA
    cur_msql.execute(values[0])

  ### CONVERT DATA
    # initialization of lists (rows tmp container)
    eachrow = []

    for row in cur_msql:

      # Here I do some other fileds conversions
      # I removed these lines because are meaningless for my problem

      # here I append the modified rows into the tmp container (list)
      eachrow.append(cur_psql.mogrify(values[2] , row))

    dataset = ','.join(eachrow)

  ### INSERT PSQL
    if dataset:    # this check value(dataset) is not empty
      try:
        cur_psql.execute( values[1] + dataset )
      except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print "Cannot execute the query on " + values[1] + dataset, e.pgerror
        cnx_psql.rollback()
        sys.exit( "Rollback! And leaving early this lucky script, find out what is wrong" )
    else:
      print "The dataset for " + key + " is empty, skipping..."

    # Cursors close
    cur_msql.close()
    cur_psql.close()
```

this is how I call my python function giving the queries in input as a python dictionary:

```python
function_args={'destination_table':[
  "SELECT resource_id, page, version, content FROM source_table",
  "INSERT INTO destination_table (resource_id, version, page, file_oid) VALUES",
  "(%(resource_id)s, %(version)s, %(page)s, lo_import('content'))"
]}

migrate_files(function_args)
```

### recap:

As you can see, what I'm trying to achieve is to directly import the stream of data(`content`) I got from mysql table into the `pg_largeobject` catalog using lo_import.

Additionally, since [here I've read](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-interfaces.html) the following:

> The return value is the OID that was assigned to the new large object

I'm also trying to directly output the `OID` was assigned to the inserted largeobject, into `file_oid` field of destination database.

Are these two operations possible?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you need "large objects"? The direct equivalent to a `longblob` is `bytea`, not a "large objects" (oid) column. You might want to have a look into `ora2pg` which also supports migration from MySQL to Postgres - maybe that can handle the `longblob` to `bytea` directly.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! yes unfortunately I'm sure of that, because the destination database is been already designed and the new version of web app is already working on the new schema, which uses large objects to manage files. About an automated solution like `ora2pg`, I already evaluated some of them, but it is not a viable path in this case, because the old schema and the new one differ to much. The differences are not limited on datatypes , a db re-design have changed the structure too deeply

Answer (score 2):

`lo_import` takes a file path as argument and imports the file contents. As you want to avoid the round-trip to the file system, that function won't do.

I haven't use Python/psycopg2 personally, but from a glance at the doc it appears the class you're looking for is [lobject](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.lobject). It provides the usual read/write/close methods wrapping the [libpq API for large objects](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-interfaces.html).

When creating a new large object, the OID that postgres assigned to it seems to be available through `lobject.oid`.